# A noun meaning 'not allowed'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word meaning "you can't do that" or "you're not allowed".

I thought of *impossibility* but I do not want it in the sense of being impossible, but in the sense of not being allowed to.

Context:

> The Sneak Out automatically provides you with a guilty conscience and the *impossibility* of telling people who you saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I'd go with **[inability](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inability)**.

> inability (n): lack of ability; lack of power, capacity, or means: *his inability to make decisions*

Comment: I suppose I will also have to change the verb tense of "telling", i.e., *inability to tell* instead of *inability of telling*

Comment: you are correct. - have an upvote

Comment: No, the OP wants a word that means you're not allowed to do this, not you're unable to do it.

Answer (score 4):

The adjective *forbidden* [means](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forbidden):

> not allowed; prohibited: a forbidden food in his religion.

The noun form of this is *forbiddenness*. Another option (which is synonymous) is *prohibition*.

Answer (score 1):

With some reorganization of your sentence, you can use words like [faux pas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faux_pas), [verboten](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verboten), [taboo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taboo), [forbidden](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forbidden), and [gauche](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gauche).

For example: "... and then it would be verboten / gauche / taboo / socially forbidden / a faux pas / a [gaffe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaffe) to reveal who you saw."

Answer (score 0):

How about "bar"

> The Sneak Out automatically provides you with a guilty conscience and bars you from telling people who you saw.

Comment: The question asked for a noun; "bars," as you've used it, is a verb.

Comment: @ect: The example used a noun, but the OP didn't make any such restriction.