# Adjective or locution showing that the absence of something is required?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any short way to say that something must be absent? If something must be present, I'd use "is required", but what can replace "must be absent", and only that? Words like "unexpected" don't fully fit the meaning I'm looking for.

This request relates to programming and I'm not sure if there is such a way to convey in a short manner, and that could be written in way to oppose "required".

The full concept is that I setup group requirements. An object may have any number of components, but to be part of a group, they must obey the group's requirements. The group says that it accepts all objects that have some components, but rejects those that have some other components.

I'd use it in a sentence similar to:

> From the point of view of the group, some specific components are required and some other specific components are __________.

And it could be also written as:

> From the point of view of the group, some specific components are required and some other specific components *must be absent*.

Comment: It would help if you said ***why*** they must not be present.

Comment: Covered at [_a noun meaning 'not allowed'_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/a-noun-meaning-not-allowed/44762#44762) (where adjectives and adjectivals are also suggested)..

Comment: Is it the case that these components are prohibited? Or is it the case that it has been found that whatever it is just doesn’t work [as well] when these components are present?

Comment: I finally could put wrap my head explaining why as precisely as possible. Sorry for the long delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general term, a past participle of a phasal verb, is "**ruled out**".

- These components are ruled out.

Another possibility is the participial adjective "**excluded**".

- These components are excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Since the context is formally logical, it is strictly necessary to differentiate between 'Must be absent in the syntactic context', or 'Must be absent in this instance'.

To define the absolute case benefits from strict words like **forbidden** and **invalid**.

Therefore to denote a local context requires a word with a more relational quality, such as **Contraindicated**, **Conflicting**, or **Unsuitable**.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider ***proscribed***

Defined by [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/proscribe)

> to officially say that something is not allowed to exist or be done

Synonyms: forbid, prohibit, disallow